# Recent closed tab menu in firefox?

Tags: firefox

I just made the switch from Opera to Firefox and one of the features I liked in Opera was a menu which showed the last tabs closed in order. I've been able to use the shift+ctrl+T to open the last closed tab, but if there's a tab I closed an hour ago I want to open again the menu was a much better option. Anyone know if there's a way to enable such a feature?

Comment: I find **Tab Mix Plus** (http://tmp.garyr.net/) gives very good tab management, including the size and other aspects of the closed tab list, which is available on the right-click context menu. When you restore a closed tab, the previous and next page lists are also restored.

Comment: Tab Mix Plus also includes a toolbar icon with a drop-down list and one-click restore of last closed tab. I too recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

If you go into History -> Recently Closed Tabs, you'll see exactly what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can install the [Undo Closed Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/undo-closed-tabs-button/) extension, which provides a button to do this.